# Regarding Interactive Charts

Tags: graphics, graph, charts

I wanted to generate interactive charts on my website inside google earth.

Can somebody suggests good open-source tools to do that. I have seen "Google Chart api" and "Simile Project". 
But I want something like FusionChart but open-source and free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at [Open Flash Chart v2](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/). It is a free (LGPL) Flash-based charting library. The charts are actually quite good looking:

[image]

Comment: Looks promising and most importantly for me, it's open source.